# How to save multi selected values?

Tags: laravel, infyom

I a have a one to many relationship between culprits and crimes and also a one to many relationship between species and crime.

culripts
id
first_name
last_name

crimes
id
culprit_id
species_id
fishing_method_id

species
id
species_name

fishing_methods
id
fishing_methods_name

What I need to achieve is to save many species for one crime

my form

```
   {{ Form::select('species_id',$speciesRepository, array('Action'), array('multiple', 'class' =>'form-control')) }}
```

my controller

```
   public function store(CreateCrimeRequest $request)
     {
         $input = $request->all();

         // $data = implode(',', $input);

        // dd($data);

          $crime = $this->crimeRepository->create($data);

          Flash::success('Crime saved successfully.');

         return redirect(route('crimes.index'));
     }
```

When I select 3 species from the dropdown the last selected species is saved while the other two are not. 
could anyone help to solve this

Comment: Well, you have to code it to create three records in your pivot table.

I assume you have a table of species

You have a table of crimes.

You need a belongsToMany relationship to store many species for one crime and a pivot table of crime_species

You will then attach species to crime

Comment: yeap it's working with the belongsToMany relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **[ ]** in your select name attribute

```
{{ Form::select('species_id[]', $speciesRepository, array('Action'), array('multiple', 'class' =>'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: hello new error arise when adding [] to species_id[] the error is Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

You're missing () here:

```
 $crime = $this->crimeRepository->create($data);
```

Must be:

```
$crime = $this->crimeRepository()->create($data);
```

You can use createMany too:

```
$crime = $this->crimeRepository()->createMany($data);
```

more examples here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to code it to create three records in your pivot table. I assume you have a table of species You have a table of crimes. You need a belongsToMany relationship to store many species for one crime and a pivot table of `crime_species` You will then attach `species` to `crime`

and You are missing **[ ]** in your select name attribute

```
{{ Form::select('species_id[]', $speciesRepository, array('Action'), array('multiple', 'class' =>'form-control')) }}
```